# Converting TZ Format

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

I'm reading in some info from an API and the time is being displayed as:

```
2021-01-29T13:29:19.668Z
```

However, I would like this to read as:

```
Jan 29, 2021 @ 1:29pm
```

Is there a way to do this with a library? Or will I have to create something myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: Btw. the title is misleading; you do not convert the time to another zone (13:29 == 1:29 PM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to explore [pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/). `pendulum` is Python's `datetime` made easy!

Just install it with:

```
$ pip install pendulum
```

Usage for your case:

```
import pendulum

dt = pendulum.parse("2021-01-29T13:29:19.668Z")
print(dt.format("MMM DD, YYYY @ h:mm A"))
```

Output:

```
Jan 29, 2021 @ 1:29 PM
```

EDIT: To get the time in `EST` (modifying the time), just do this:

```
import pendulum

dt = pendulum.parse("2021-01-29T13:29:19.668Z")
print(dt.in_tz("America/Toronto").format("MMM DD, YYYY @ h:mm A"))
```

Output:

```
Jan 29, 2021 @ 8:29 AM
```

However, if you don't want to modify the output but just set the timezone, try this:

```
dt = pendulum.parse("2021-01-29T13:29:19.668Z").set(tz="America/Toronto")
print(dt.timezone)
print(dt)
print(dt.format("MMM DD, YYYY @ h:mm A"))
```

Output:

```
Timezone('America/Toronto')
2021-01-29T13:29:19.668000-05:00
Jan 29, 2021 @ 1:29 PM
```

Comment: This is perfect. One more slight twist. If this is GMT 0 time. How would I change it to EST time ? (-5 hours)

Comment: I was able to do this using:
dt = dt.subtract(hours=5)

Comment: one small other thing. 3:00PM was showing as 3:PM I fixed this by :
From:
`print(dt.format("MMM DD, YYYY @ h:m A"))`

to:
`print(dt.format("MMM DD, YYYY @ h:mm A"))`

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime

string_time = "2021-01-29T13:29:19.668Z"

# see https://strftime.org/ for definitions of strftime directives
dt_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"

output_format = "%b %d, %Y @ %-I:%-M%p" # the %p is uppercase AM or PM

output = datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(string_time, dt_format), output_format)

# lower case the last 2 characters of output
# and join with all characters except the last 2
print(''.join((output[:-2], output[-2:].lower())))
```

OUTPUT: `Jan 29, 2021 @ 1:29pm`

Answer (score -1):

I used the datetime module.
And used the split function to separate the date from the time and the rest as well

```
import datetime

DT = "2021-01-29T13:29:19.668Z"

date,time = DT.split("T")

Year, Month, Day = date.split("-")

Hour, Minute, Seconds = time.split(":")

x = datetime.datetime( int(Year), int(Month), int(Day), int(Hour), int(Minute) )

x = x.strftime("%b %d, %Y @ %I:%M %p")

output = ''.join(( x[:-2], x[-2:].lower() ))

print(output)
```